# 'clr-date-container' is not a known element:

Tags: vmware-clarity, clarity

I am trying to use the clarity date picker as shown below in an Angular Template

```
<div class="col-6 dateCont">
    <clr-date-container>
        <input type="date" clrDate name="open" [(ngModel)]="demo">
    </clr-date-container>
</div>
```

The Docs do not specify anything about any additional stuff that might need to be imported in the component so I did not include anything. Clarity is properly added to the app.module.ts and other clarity stuff are working okay.  Could anyone assist with what I could possibley be doing wrong.

The error is shown like this in the browser console
[image]

Comment: It sounds like either 1) You aren't including the Clarity module or 2) You are using an older version that doesn't have the `clr-date-container`. Can you verify versions of Clarity and if possible create an isolated demo in Stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/@clr-team has starters

Comment: @JeremyWilken i am using clarity 2.2 and Angular 8

Comment: Would you be able to post a stackblitz that recreates the issue so we can look at a real app?

Comment: Please post your package.json and a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)